pypfopt EfficientFrontier.plotting do not working
I'm working on a Python project for portfolio optimization using the PyPortfolioOpt library. When I try to import the plotting module and plot the efficient frontier, I get the following error:
oserror: 'seaborn-deep' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in `style.available`)

Here's a simplified version of my code:
# Importation of libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pypfopt import EfficientFrontier, risk_models, expected_returns, plotting

# ... (data loading and processing)

# Plotting the efficient frontier
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S, weight_bounds=(0, 1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))

# Generate the efficient frontier
plotting.plot_efficient_frontier(ef, ax=ax, show_assets=False)

# Mark the minimum volatility portfolio
ef.min_volatility()
ret_min_vol, vol_min_vol, _ = ef.portfolio_performance()
ax.scatter(vol_min_vol, ret_min_vol, marker='*', s=200, c='r', label='Minimum Volatility Portfolio')

# Mark the maximum Sharpe ratio portfolio
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S)
ef.max_sharpe()
ret_max_sharpe, vol_max_sharpe, _ = ef.portfolio_performance()
ax.scatter(vol_max_sharpe, ret_max_sharpe, marker='*', s=200, c='g', label='Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio')

# Labels and titles
ax.set_title('Efficient Frontier')
ax.set_xlabel('Volatility (Risk)')
ax.set_ylabel('Expected Return')
ax.legend()
plt.show()


When I run this code, I get the error mentioned above. However, if I remove the plotting module and the plotting code, everything runs fine.
I've tried the following to fix the issue:
Reinstalled PyPortfolioOpt using pip install PyPortfolioOpt --upgrade.
Installed older versions of PyPortfolioOpt to see if the issue persists.
Ensured that seaborn and matplotlib are up to date by running pip install seaborn --upgrade and pip install matplotlib --upgrade.
Verified that seaborn is installed and can be imported without issues.
Additional Information:
I'm using Python 3.12.
My current versions of the packages are:
PyPortfolioOpt: 1.5.5
matplotlib: 3.8.0
seaborn: 0.13.0
The output of plt.style.available does not include 'seaborn-deep'.
Questions:
Why am I getting this error when importing plotting from PyPortfolioOpt?
Is there a compatibility issue with Python 3.12 or specific versions of matplotlib or seaborn?
How can I fix this error so I can plot the efficient frontier using PyPortfolioOpt?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
